# Android Preferences defaultValue not works

Tags: android, android-preferences

Here is my preferences.xml

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_cat_recognition">
    <ListPreference
        android:entries="@array/unitsArray"
        android:entryValues="@array/unitsValues"
        android:icon="@null"
        android:key="unit"
        android:summary="@string/units_summary"
        android:title="@string/units"
        android:defaultValue="1"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

and my array.xml

```
<string-array name="unitsArray" translatable="false">
    <item>cm</item>
    <item>inch</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="unitsValues" translatable="false">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
</string-array>
```

So it should be `cm` checked on start but there is no value checked. Why and how to solve that to have a value `cm` on start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out in manifest I had `android:allowBackup="true"`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine. The reason why you dont see the selected value on the summary is because you have specified a custom summary text. You can use `useSimpleSummaryProvider` to enable the simple version of summary, also enabling the selected value seen without opening the preference.

Pls check my code below for clarity of things:

```
`<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<PreferenceCategory app:title="Choose Gender">
    <ListPreference
        app:defaultValue="m"
        app:entries="@array/gender_entries"
        app:entryValues="@array/gender_values"
        app:key="gender"
        app:title="Your Gender"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />
</PreferenceCategory>


<PreferenceCategory app:title="StackOverflow">
    <ListPreference
        app:defaultValue="1"
        app:entries="@array/unitsArray"
        app:entryValues="@array/unitsValues"
        app:key="unit"
        app:title="Units"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />

    <ListPreference
        app:defaultValue="1"
        app:entries="@array/unitsArray"
        app:entryValues="@array/unitsValues"
        app:key="unit"
        app:summary="Your summary goes here"
        app:title="Units" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

`

[This is the preference screen view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6QQU.jpg)

If the summary was provided you'd be seeing the summary text and not the default/selected value like in the picture above.

Comment: But you misunderstood. I do have summary, I do not have any defaultValue at start.

Comment: The default value is being selected as 'cm' in my case. Did you try rebuilding and running the app?

Comment: Hmm I will try rebuilding. Does defaultValue means value on start?

Comment: Rebuilding didnt help